# createServer: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: http, httpserver

I'm trying to configure the MIME type on my http server and set the `Content-Type` to `text/html`, but I'm receiving this error:

> (node:87702) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

This is what my code looks like:

```
const handler = require('serve-handler');
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.statusCode = 200;
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  response.end();

  handler(request, response);
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Running at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I've pretty much copied the example from the [library's (serve) README](https://github.com/zeit/serve#api).

I don't have much experience with this to understand what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (node:87702) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client

Try to move this line `handler(request, response)` upward, like so:

```
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  handler(request, response); //move here

  response.statusCode = 200;
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  response.end();
})
```

Because of [response.end()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) statement:

> This method signals to the server that all of the response headers and
>   body have been sent; that server should consider this message
>   complete.

Therefore, when the `handler(request, response)` middleware trying to set headers to the response, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You are ending the response with your `response.end()`. This means the head and body have been sent to the client. Therefore, `handler`, when it runs, when it tries to set response properties, it will be unable to because the response has already been sent.

I'm guessing you don't need that `response.end()`. It's not clear it serves any purpose.